# Ways to export Wireframe project (e.g. Mockplus) to Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, wireframe

Regarding the upstream process of Android Apps Development, Wireframing, I am trying to find a way to export my wireframe (e.g. Mockplus) into usable items (xml) into my android studio.

Is it possible to do so with Mockplus or with other wireframing software(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately It is not possible But we can use css and java. These wireframe app reduce time for prototyping.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for a design tool, where we can prototype and import as an android activity xml. Looks like there is no one as such. Tried mockplus, flinto, adobe xd none of these have that options. It is double the effort.